# NP-hardness language

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

How to prove that language $L = \{G \; | \; \omega(G) \geq \frac{9}{10}\cdot n\}$, where $n$ - number of vertices in the graph, NP-hard?

$\omega$ - is a clique number.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following reduction from the NP-complete problem $Clique = \{ \langle G, k\rangle \ : \text{G is undirected Graph that has a clique of size at least k}\}$ to $L$. The reduction operates as follows.

Given input $\langle G = (V, E), k \rangle\in Clique$:

1. If $k < \frac{9\cdot|V|}{10}$, output $G' = G \cup K_{t}$, where $t= 9\cdot |V| -10k$, and $K_t$ is the complete graph over $t$ vertices. In addition, add edges that connect every vertex in $K_{t}$ with every vertex in $G$.
2. Othwerwise, if $k \geq \frac{9\cdot|V|}{10}$, output $G'$ that is defined as follows. $G'$ is obtained by replacing each vertex of $v \in V$ by a clique of size 9, denoted $c_9(v)$, and then for every edge $\{ u, v\}\in E$, the two cliques $c_9(v), c_9(u)$ in $G'$ are connected, that is, every vertex of $c_9(v)$ is connected by an edge with every vertex of $c_9(u)$. Also, add to $G'$ new $t$ isolated vertices, where $t= 10k - 9|V|$.

Correctness:

1. If $k < \frac{9\cdot|V|}{10}$, then note that $t = 9\cdot |V| - 10k >
       0$, and so the output of the reduction $G'$ is well-defined. Now if $G$
   has a clique $C$ of size at least $k$, then $G'$ has a clique of
   size at least $k+t$ (verify that $C\cup \{ v: \text{$v$ is a vertex
   in $K_t$}\}$ is a clique of $G'$). Conversely, if $G'$ has a clique
   of $C'$ of size at least $k + t$, then the set $C = C' \setminus \{
   v: v \text{ is a vertex of $K_t$} \}$ is a clique of $G$. Indeed,
   the reduction does not add new edges between the vertices of $G$.
   Also note that $C$ is of size $|C| \geq |C'| - | \{ v: v \text{ is a
   vertex of $K_t$} \}| = |C'| - t \geq k+t - t = k$ in $G$. All in
   all, we have that $G$ has a clique of size at least $k$ iff $G'$ has
   a clique of size at least $k+t$. Finally, note that
   $\frac{k+t}{|G'|} = \frac{k+t}{|V|+t} = \frac{k + 9|V| - 10k}{|V| +
   9|V| - 10k} = \frac{9|V| - 9k}{10|V|-10k} = \frac{9}{10}$. So, $G$
   has a clique of size at least $k$ iff $G'$ has a clique of size at
   least $k+t = \frac{9}{10} |G'|$.
2. If $k \geq\frac{9\cdot|V|}{10}$, then note that  $10k - 9|V| \geq 0$, and so the output of the reduction $G'$ is well-defined. For the first direction, if $G$ has a clique $C$ of size at least $k$, then $G'$ has a clique $C'$ of size at least $9k$. Indeed, we can take $C' = \bigcup_{v\in C} c_9(v)$, that is, $C'$ consists of the 9-cliques corresponding to the vertices in $C$ (verify that $C'$ is indeed a clique of size at least $9k$ in $G'$). The following holds $\frac{|C'|}{|G'|} \geq \frac{9k}{|G'|} =
   \frac{9k}{9|V|+t} = \frac{9k}{9|V| +10k-9|V| }
    =
   \frac{9}{10}$. So $G'$ has a clique of size at least $\frac{9|G'|}{10}$. Conversely, assume that $G'$ has a clique $C'$ of size at least $\frac{9|G'|}{10} = \frac{9\cdot (9|V| + t)}{10} = \frac{9\cdot(9|V| + 10k - 9|V|)}{10} = \frac{9\cdot 10k}{10} = 9k$. Clearly, none of the added isolated vertices are in $C'$, and thus $C'$ consists of vertices $p$ such that $p\in c_9(v)$ for some $v\in V$. In words, $C'$ consists of vertices $p$ such that $p$ belongs to one of the 9-cliques of $G'$. Note that there could be two vertices $p_1, p_2\in C'$ such that both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are in $c_9(v)$ for some $v\in V$ (that is, $C'$ can have vertices that correspond to the same 9-clique). Now consider the following set $C =\{ v\in V: \text{ there is $p\in C'$ such that $p\in c_9(v)$} \}$. We claim that $C$ is a clique of size at least $k$ in $G$, and thus we're done. To begin with, $|C|\geq k$ because for every $v\in C$ there are at most 9 $p$'s such that $p\in c_9(v)$ and $p\in C'$, and those 9 $p$'s correspond only to the vertex $v$ in $C$. So in the worst case, $C'$ consists of whole 9-cliques and we replace every 9-clique $c_9(v)$ with $v$ to get the set $C$. So, as $|C'|\geq 9k$, then $|C|\geq k$. Now to show that $C$ is a clique in $G$, let $v_1, v_2$ be two vertices in $C$. We need to show that $\{u, v \}\in E$. By definition of $C$, there are $p_1, p_2 \in C'$ such that $p_1\in c_9(v_1)$ and $p_2\in c_9(v_2)$. Since $C'$ is a clique of $G'$, we know that $\{p_1, p_2 \}$ is an edge of $G'$, and by definition of $G'$ this can happen only when $\{v_1, v_2 \} \in E$ (indeed, vertices of different 9-cliques are connected in $G'$ when the vertices defining the 9-cliques are connected in G).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what other problems you already know to be NP-hard and whether you use Karp or Turing reductions.

Comment: I am using Karp reductions. Regarding the number of NP-hard languages, I am sure that whatever language you use to solve this problem, I am most likely familiar with it.